# React Native fbsdk adding permissions

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk

I would like to use different, and add multiple, login permissions using the react native fbsdk and LoginButton. The only permission that seem to work is the publish_actions permissions but I would also like access the users friends:

works: publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}

Would like to write: publishPermissions={["public_profile, friends"]}

When I log in to grant these permissions I receive the below message in Xcode and the simulator crashes:

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));  Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Does anyone have a clue how this can be resolved? Do I need to use the LoginManager instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the readPermissions property of the Facebook Login button

e.g use readPermissions={["email","public_profile","user_friends"]}